# How to launch a mouse click button with PowerShell?

Tags: shell, internet-explorer, powershell, search-engine

Good Morning everyone, I am a beginner in PowerShell Scripting and I am trying to make a powerShell script. The goal is to automatically install Google search engine in the Internet web browser.
Here the link for the add-on : http://www.iegallery.com/Addons/Details/1674

The URL of Google which ask the user if he wants to add Google as the default web browser is :
http://www.google.com/search?q=&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft&ie=&oe=

I would like my script to automatically click "OK" at the question "Gagnez du temps avec Google. Mettez à jour votre moteur de recherche par défaut." which it basically means "update your web broswer with Google. Here the start of my script

```PS
$pathURL = "http://www.google.com/search?q=&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft&ie=&oe="


$ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible = $true 
$ie.silent = $true 
$ie.Navigate($pathURL)
```

does anyone know how to initiate a click to click "OK" ?

I found this kind of code into another topic, but I don't know how to use it for my script :

```PS
#while($ie.busy){Start-Sleep 1} 
#$secLink = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | Where-Object {$_.innerText -eq 'Gagnez du temps avec Google. Mettez à jour votre moteur de recherche par défaut.'} 
#$secLink.click()
```

Thank You,
Mickael

Comment: have you considered just overwriting the searchscope in the registry instead of this? here is a link that covers that approach: http://www.adamfowlerit.com/2014/01/08/how-to-change-ie10s-default-search-engine/

Comment: $ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.navigate("http://")
do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))
$doc = $ie.document
$button = $doc.getElementById("TheButtonHTML-ID")
$button.click();